Remote Notification/Alarm in Flutter
I am working on a Flutter App, where Managers can assign Tasks to the users. They can send the request to the users in the App, where they can accept/reject the tasks. Whenever they receive a task request, I want the notification to be somewhat like an alert, similar to phone call, so they can only accept or reject. I don't want to use the simple push notifications.
I want to know which tools or libraries should be helpful for this.
Also it has to work even if the App is terminated.
I tried Push Notification, but they are not that useful in this scenario, because the tasks are somehow urgent, they need quick response, and they are easily to be missed. Also I am using OneSignal for the Push Notification for other features, please let me know if I can do something also similar using OneSignal Push Notification.
